# Plotting histograms with Arabic characters

Tags: python, matplotlib, character-encoding, seaborn, arabic

I am trying to plot an histogram of most frequent words written in `arabic`, but I can't figure out a way to do that. All I can get is the sliced characters but not the compiled word.

Here is an example of what I get :

[image]

```
import seaborn as sns

import pandas as pd

res = {
 'الذكاء': 8,
 'الاصطناعي': 9,
 'هو': 2,
 'سلوك': 1,
 'وخصائص': 1,
 'معينة': 1,
 'تتسم': 1
}

df = pd.DataFrame(res.items(), columns=['word', 'count'])

sns.set(style="whitegrid")
ax = sns.barplot(x="count", y="word", data=df)
```

As shown in the image above, I am expecting to get those characters compiled, like they're mentioned in the dictionary.

Comment: Did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15421746/matplotlib-writing-right-to-left-text-hebrew-arabic-etc) and [this (similar)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18772950/right-to-left-support-in-python-networkx-and-matplotlib)?

Comment: @Sheldore I have seen this answer before but couldn't find a way to integrate it in my problem. He's plotting a full text there, in my case it's an histogram that would have arabic labels

Comment: Yes, but you can use the same way to generate a list of compatible tick labels using `bidi` package

Comment: I can't run your code because something weird happens with my cursor controls when I try to modify your dictionary `res`. Things start to type from right to left

Comment: @Sheldore I have just tried to create a new dictionary and append to it the same keys applying on them the `arabic_reshaper.reshape` function but with no further result still got the same output.

Comment: @saul have you had a chance to test [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68221670/16343464)?

Answer (score 4):

This seems to run well with `arabic_reshaper` and `bidi` as pointed out by @Sheldore.

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display

res = {
 'الذكاء': 8,
 'الاصطناعي': 9,
 'هو': 2,
 'سلوك': 1,
 'وخصائص': 1,
 'معينة': 1,
 'تتسم': 1
}

res2 = {get_display(arabic_reshaper.reshape(k)): v for k,v in res.items()}

df = pd.DataFrame(res2.items(), columns=['word', 'count'])

sns.set(style="whitegrid")
ax = sns.barplot(x="count", y="word", data=df)
```

[image: barplot with arabic labels]

Comment: Don't forget to install the packages using `pip install arabic-reshaper python-bidi`

Comment: arabic-reshaper and python-bidi are hacks. python-bidi attempts to reorder text to visual rather than logical order, and arabic-reshaper swaps the Arabic codepoint for deprecated Arabic presentational forms. A more robust approach is to change the matplotlib backend to mplcairo which uses raqm (which in turn uses fribidi (or sheen) and harfbuzz) for complext text rendering and bidirectional algotirthm.